# how to place a character where it was after manipulating the string?

Tags: java, string, punctuation

So I am doing a pig latin assignment, and lets say the user gives you "Car"

so the end result is "arCay" the original word, take first letter, put it to the end, and add an "ay". i have done all this so far.

But i'm stuck at the punctuation part. How can I do it so that if the user tells me "Car!"
the end result will be "arCay!". For example, "!Hello!" should be "!Ellohay!"

exc is the CharSequence "!" excMark is the char '!' excMarkLocation is it's location

a2, e2, etc. are just chars, which stand for 'A' 'E' etc.

Code:

```
[code][java]
if(Character.isUpperCase(s.charAt(0)))

{

if((s.charAt(0)==a2) || (s.charAt(0)==e2) || (s.charAt(0)==i2) || (s.charAt(0)==o2) || (s.charAt(0)==u2))


 {


 if(s.contains(exc))

 {

excMarkLocation=s.indexOf(excMark);

s=s.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]", "");

temp2 = (s+"way");

s=temp2;

s=s+'!';

 }

else

{

temp2 = (s+"way");

s=temp2;

}[/java][/code]
```

Sorry, what are the tags I should use?

Answer (score 0):

When you add the ay to the resulting string, try checking the last character and if it matches a punctuation character (using regex) then insert the "ay" at string.length -2.

That seems like it would work to me.  Hope it helps.

Comment: So Car becomes arCay
Car! becomes arCay!

How does what you said work? the punctuation should remain at the sequence it was at at the beginning.

Comment: It makes sense to me from what you said, maybe you should clarify what you are trying to do because it doesn't seem like it would be that complicated, unless I'm just totally misunderstanding what you are trying to do.